# TYPO3 error: the controller "Standard" is not allowed by plugin "diagnoseList"

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

TYPO3 8.7.17, I develop an extension, and suddenly I got error.

```
The controller "Standard" is not allowed by plugin "diagnoseList". Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.
```

ext_localconf.php:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Il.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'diagnoseList',
    [
        'Evil' => 'diagnoseList, showDiagnoseSystemCategoryContent, showDiagnoseSystemEvilContent',
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        'Evil' => 'diagnoseList, showDiagnoseSystemCategoryContent, showDiagnoseSystemEvilContent',
    ]
);
```

Also I have a controller:

```
namespace Il\Evil\Controller;

use Il\Evil\Domain\Model\DiagnoseSystemCategory;
use Il\Evil\Domain\Model\DiagnoseSystemEvil;
use Il\Evil\Domain\Model\HomeopathyCategory;
use Il\Evil\Domain\Model\HomeopathyEvil;

    class EvilController extends BasicController
    {
        public function diagnoseListAction()
        {
            $mainCategories = $this->diagnoseSystemCategoryRepository->findMainCategories();

            $mainCategoriesRows = array_chunk($mainCategories, 3);

            $this->view->assign('mainCategoriesRows', $mainCategoriesRows);
            $this->view->assign('currentPid', $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id);
            $this->view->assign('currentPageTitle', $GLOBALS['TSFE']->rootLine[1]['title']);

        }
    }
```

Also I have a view file, I will not attach the code, it is not important. All configurations and code looks right. I have checked everything several times, cleared the cache, reinstalled extension. Another plugin which is configured by the such way works well. Really stupid error.

Comment: Do you have any flexform configuration attached to this plugin?

Comment: no, nothing. But I noticed if I deactivate realurl - then it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deactivated real_url extension, deleted all real_url tables, activated real_url extension. Then it works.